# Google Notifier hangs on sign-in, must be force-quit (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, troubleshooting, crash, google-notifier

OS X 10.6.7 and GN 1.10.7. It was working fine. Then suddenly it started hanging whenever I tried to sign in, regardless of which account. Just gives me the spinning loading icon (not spinning pinwheel, but the sun-dial like circle), for eternity until I force-quit. (Doesn't even get the icon into the menubar.)

- I replaced the app in `/Applications` with a fresh one from the dmg and it didn't work.
- I deleted `com.google.GmailNotifier.plist` and again replaced the app and it DID work. But then after a couple of days, it stopped working again.
- Now I have deleted `com.google.GmailNotifier.plist` AND deleted the Google Notifier folder from ~/Library/Caches/Google AND replaced the app fresh and still, just hangs when I try to login.

I'm stuck!

PS: I have Secrets preference pane installed and it has entries (which I have not touched) for Google Notifier, but I'm reluctant to think this is the problem since somehow it worked even with said prefpane installed after one replacement once?

Comment: Do you see any relevant output in Utilities/Console.app under "All Messages"/"Console Messages", when the Notifier hangs?

Comment: @slhck Good idea I didn't try, but sadly no, just the notice that it was "Exited: Killed" after I force-quit it.

Comment: Hmm, then unfortunately I'm out of ideas for now..